# How do you catch an exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception, methods, queue, try-catch

I've been trying to output "Queue is full" which was declared in my other code. How do I catch this?

this is my main

```cpp
int main() {
    IntQueue iQueue(5);
    try {
        cout << "Enqueuing 5 items...\n";
        // Enqueue 5 items.
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            iQueue.enqueue(x);
    } catch (...) {
        // Attempt to enqueue a 6th item.
        cout << "Now attempting to enqueue again...\n";
        iQueue.enqueue(5);
    }
```

and this is my other code

```cpp
if (isFull())
    throw std::runtime_error("Queue is full");
else {
    cout << "Enqueueing: " << num << endl;
    // Calculate the new rear position
    rear = (rear + 1) % queueSize;
    // Insert new item
    queueArray[rear] = num;
    // Update item count
    numItems++;
}
```

Comment: `iQueue.enqueue(5);` in the catch block throws another exception?

Answer (score 0):

Any code under the `catch` block is meant to *catch* any exception thrown in the `try` block, which means you should write any code that could throw exceptions in it:

```
try {
    // trying to enqueue 6 items, which is above limit.
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) { 
        iQueue.enqueue(x);
    }
} catch (exception e) { 
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you catch an exception and print its message:

```
try {
   // ...
} catch (std::runtime_error const& e) {
   std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; // or std::cerr, std::perror, or smth else
}
```